# invalid syntax elif python

Tags: python

i got an error invalid syntax elif when running python flask, here is my code

```
    elif "form_jokowi" in request.form:
        elif "form_prabowo" in request.form:
            with open('crawldatauser.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
                tweet_result = list(reader)

                validated_tweet_positif = []
                validated_tweet_negatif = []
```

the error if i validate from form prabowo, how can i fix them?

Comment: The inner `elif` (and maybe the outer one) doesn't have an `if`.

Comment: Why have you got one elif inside another? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: An *elif* must be preceded by an *if* (at the **same indent level**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it possible you only need a regular `if`?

try replacing the `elif`s with `if`:

```py
if "form_jokowi" in request.form:
    if "form_prabowo" in request.form:
        with open('crawldatauser.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            tweet_result = list(reader)

            validated_tweet_positif = []
            validated_tweet_negatif = []
```